# Why extra space and how to remove it?

Tags: line-spacing, ieeetran

I'm using:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}    
\begin{document}
%
\begin{enumerate}
\item something 
\item something
\end{enumerate}
%
I have an empty line space just before this line.
\end{document}
```

I don't know why there is a line space before "I have an empty ...". How do I remove it?

Thanks

Comment: (Enumerate) lists do have such space, to make them more outstanding

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Isn't "%" supposed to remove the extra spaces?

Comment: Not in this case, as there is some extra `\vskip\somelength` statement in the end code of `\enumerate` (at least as far as I remember). I tried your document and the spacings are not too large, in my point of view

Comment: The code posted [produces this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ys9xz.png) do you really want the last line closer to the display list?

Comment: Mine is at least 3 lines of space!?

Answer (score 2):

The standard behavior of `enumerate` lists is to add some vertical space above and below them (unless they are nested and start just after `\item`).

This space is `\topsep` and is used both above and below.

So you get no space by setting it to zero and `enumerate` in the `IEEEtran` class accepts an optional argument for doing shose settings.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[\setlength\topsep{0pt}]
\item something
\item something
\end{enumerate}
I have an empty line space just before this line.
\end{document}
```

Of course no space will be left above the list (you can add it manually with `\vspace{\topsep}`.

[image]

A more complete example, showing the difference. I think that the space is good, because it makes the list a bit more outstanding from the context.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]
\begin{enumerate}
\item something 
\item something
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{enumerate}[\setlength\topsep{0pt}]
\item something 
\item something
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: in my code posted above, I do not have any space above the list nut only after the list.

Comment: your code doesn't work for me. I still have the space after the list.

Comment: @Elnaz What version of IEEEtran do you have?

Comment: I just downloaded it few months ago. I'm using ''\documentclass[journal,transmag]{IEEEtran}'', if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Elnaz I get exactly what I showed in the picture. Note that `IEEEtran` is included in TeX Live, where did you download it?

Comment: I am using overleaf, the online editor; it already supports all classes.